# Using rails simple form to update multiple records at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, simple-form

I am trying to create a simple form, that has 2 fields. But I want to set these 2 fields for multiple active records at once. I have created a new controller action called update multiple, but somehow my form is just not displaying. I am not sure how I could do this with active records. Here is my code:

```
<% simple_form_for @fulfillments,
 :url => admin_fulfillments_update_multiple_path,
 :method => :put,
 remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :ids, value: @fulfillments %>
  <%= f.input :shopper_id, id: 'fulfillment_shopper_id', collection: @shoppers, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, label: 'Shopper', include_blank: true%>
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn btn-success btn-sm submit-shopper-form' %>
<% end %>
```

@fulfillments has been populated in a different action of the controller already, and now I am passing it through the form, as a hidden field, to another controller action. But somehow

I am not sure why is my form not displaying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a `=` in the simple form:
yours:

```
<% simple_form_for @fulfillments,
```

correct:

```
<%= simple_form_for @fulfillments,
```

Notice the **<%=**. at the beginning.